# post data on server in blackberry

Tags: java

hi 
I m new in development blackberry application. I want post email and password to the server(`http://dev.7-yes.com/ws7Yes/SecurityService.asmx?op=LoginUser`). so how i done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpURLConnection` to make HTTP request to web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kSoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) api to call our web service so that it can use post email & password to the server.